# Can I do a save in docker after some manual installation?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image, docker-for-windows

I'd like to know if this is possible in docker? and how?

I have a minimal image created using a minimal Dockerfile.

Then I "run" this image interactively and get a cmd window (or shell).

Now I'd like to perform some manual installations which I do not want to code in the Dockerfile.

Once I'm done I'd like to save this either as a new image or right over the original image i started with at the time of "run"
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the container in a new image using [docker container commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_commit/)

```
docker container commit [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]
```

Description from the docs:

> Create a new image from a container’s changes

Answer (score 0):

This sort of defeats the purpose of Docker, where the image runtime is immutable.  You should add RUN lines in the Dockerfile to perform the installations (e.g. apt-get install -y commands) and then do a docker build.

Comment: That is the preferred way to do things.  But it seems that in this particular case, OP just does not know how to do the install from a command line.  For example, I would like to create an image with google chromium on it and some useful chrome extensions pre-installed.  I do not know how to install extensions from the command line, so I would be in the same position as the OP.

Comment: It does not. Not everything is scriptable or worth scripting